# C# MVC 3 Generates Link With Unnecessary Parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm new to .Net. I'm close to the end of my first project, and I've run into a trivial issue that's bothering me. I'm using MVC 3, Razor, C#, and VisualStudio 2010.

The following is the Razor code I have for redirecting the user to different RDLC reports:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Length of stay for all data packages - summary", "RptLngthStay", "Reports", new { @class = "link" })<br />
@Html.ActionLink("Packages denied registration by WHS reviewers", "RptPkgsDenied", "Reports", new { @class = "link" })<br />
<...>
```

It generates the following HTML:

```
<a class="link" href="/reg_pkgs/Reports/RptLngthStay?Length=7">Length of stay for all data packages - summary</a><br />
<a class="link" href="/reg_pkgs/Reports/RptPkgsDenied?Length=7">Packages denied registration by WHS reviewers</a><br />
<...>
```

My question is, where is the parameter "Length=7" coming from? None of the controllers require a parameter, let alone one named "Length." It doesn't affect how any of my code runs, but seeing it in the address bar is bothering me.

Here are the routes in my Global.asax.cs file:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "PackageTrack", action = "TrackSearch", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );
}
```

They're just the default routes that are created with a new project.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong overload of `Html.ActionLink` which has the signature [(HtmlHelper, String, String, Object, Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492124).

Where the third parameter `"Reports"` is interpreted as the rootvalues object, and the framework tries to get it's properties. And the string `"Reports"` has one property Lenght which is equals to 7.

What you need is the overload with the signature [(HtmlHelper, String, String, String, Object, Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972.aspx)

Change your code to:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Link text", "RptLngthStay", "Reports", null,  new { @class = "link" })<br />
@Html.ActionLink("Link text", "RptPkgsDenied", "Reports", null, new { @class = "link" })<br />
```

Note the `null`s as the 4th parameter.

Comment: That fixed it. I feel like a moron. I used nulls throughout the rest of the program, and managed to miss them here. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
@Html.ActionLink("Packages denied registration by WHS reviewers", "RptLngthStay", "Reports", null, new { @class = "link" })
```

or

```
@Html.ActionLink("Packages denied registration by WHS reviewers", "RptLngthStay", "Reports", new {}, new { @class = "link" })
```

The HTML helper needs to have the route data value so that it can distinguish between the routedata and htmlAttribute properties.

Comment: Thanks, this was the right answer as well, but @nemesv answered first. I'd give both of you the checkmark if I could.